# Rotate a polygon so its edge matches up with another

Tags: geometry

I have two convex polygons, ***A*** and ***B***. Given a specific side on each, I need to translate and rotate ***B*** so that the centerpoint of both lines coincide and the lines become parallel, giving the appearance of creating a new more complex polygon.

The translation is easy, but I can't figure out how to do the rotation. I thought just taking the angle between the vector between the center of ***A*** and the center of ***A***'s side, and the corresponding vector on ***B***, and rotating ***B*** by the angle between them, but this doesn't work, and I'm out of ideas. Help?

For example: in this image, ***B***'s center is in the right place, but it needs to rotate 195 degrees so that its 0th side matches up to ***A***'s 0th side. I determined that answer through trial and error in this case; is there an analytic solution for any two polygons?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we want the edge $e_A$ of $A$ with center $c_A$ to match up with the edge $e_B$ with center $c_B$ in the way you describe.
Here's a way to construct a euclidean transformation that achieves this.

First, we translate $B$ by a translation $\tau$ such that $c_A$ and $c_B$ match up. You can do this easily with the translation $\tau(x) = x + (c_A - c_B)$. Then $\tau(c_B) = c_A$.

Next, we rotate $B$. However, we will not rotate $B$ around its center, but rather around $c_B$. You can get the correct angle $\theta$ by interpreting $v_A - c_A$ and $v_B - c_B$ as complex numbers and then taking the argument of their ratio,
where $v_A$ is the vertex of $A$ that comes counter-clockwise *before* $c_A$, and $v_B$ is the vertex of $B$ that comes conter-clockwise *after* $c_B$ (this needs to be taken into consideration because otherwise the polygons might end up intersecting). In symbols:

$$\theta = \arg \frac{v_A - c_A}{v_B - c_B}.$$

Let $\rho$ be the rotation around $c_A$ by an angle of $\theta$. Then the composition $\rho \circ \tau$ should do what you want.